# moving from $y=f(x)$ equation back to parametric equations

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Looking at a Khan video, he works a problem in which he goes from the parametric equations:
$$
x = 3 \cos t ,\quad y=2 \sin t
$$ 
to eliminating t and yielding the equation for an ellipse:
$$
\frac{x^2}{9} + \frac{y^2}{4} = 1.
$$
that's nice. We went from the parametic equations to the $y = f(x)$ style equation. Now, how would we go backwards? i.e.

given the equation of an ellipse $\frac{x^2}{9} + \frac{y^2}{4} = 1$ and requiring that we start at $\theta = 0$ and going counterclockwise, and requiring a period of $2 \pi$, how do we derive the parametric equations?

In his next video, Khan points out that you can't really go backwards because there are an infinite set of parametric equations but then he does go on to give one example, so my question is: what set of choices would you have to make to get back to the original parametric equations?

Thanks,
Chris

Comment: backwards, there is not one unique way. there may be many ways. in your example, even a simple tweak allows, you $x = 3\cos (kt), y = 2 \sin kt$ for any $k \neq 0.$ you can have $x = 3(1-t^2)/(1+t^2), 4t/(1+t^2)$ and so on.

Answer (score 1):

There is no general rule to single out a parametrization. In your case, if $X=3x$ and $Y=2y$, then
$$
X^2+Y^2=1,
$$
and you can parametrize this circle as $X=\cos \theta$, $Y=\sin \theta$. Therefore $x=3 \cos \theta$, $y=2 \sin \theta$. In other words, you have reduced an ellipse to a circle, for which there exists a standard parametrization.

However, for a general curve
$$
F(x,y)=0
$$
like yours, there is no guarantee that you will be able to find a parametrization. If $F$ is a polynomial, I can remember that much more can be said (I apologize, but I am a mathematical analyst and my memories of plane algebraic curves are rather old and weak).

Answer (score 0):

Several possibilities exist. Imagine two parameters whose squared sum is 1 to describe an ellipse.

$$ ( \cos c t, \sin c t), ( sech \, t , \tanh t ), (  \sqrt t  ,  \sqrt{1-  t} ), \, etc. $$ 
So the first quantity in each case = $ x/3 $ and, second  $= y/2$ in such parametrization.

In the last two cases,   $ -\infty < t < \infty , 0 < t < 1.  $